# const pointer throws compilation error

Tags: c, pointers, constants

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a[] = { 10, 11 };
    int * const ptr = a;

    *ptr = 11; /* Here the value should be properly changed as I have taken 
      const pointer (address of the pointer can not be changed) and not pointer to 
      const (data pointed by the pointer can not be changed) */

    printf("\n value at ptr is : [%d]\n", *ptr);
    printf("\n Address pointed by ptr : [%p]\n", (unsigned int*)ptr);

    ptr++;
    printf("\n Address pointed by ptr : [%p]\n", (unsigned int*)ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

In above program I am taking `const` pointer that means if I change the address it is pointing to then it should give error, but I am just changing the value pointed by it, as per the guide line of const pointer it should be able to change the value, and if I try to change the address then it should return error, but why I am getting compilation error in above code?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the (properly formatted) error.

Comment: The error message should be very clear. Why do you try to modify a pointer you explicitly guaranteed you will not? And the casts in your `printf` invoke undefined behaviour. Please read the documentation of `printf` which pointer type is expected.

Comment: It would be good to know in *exactly* which line do you get compilation error in question?

Comment: Had you actually read the still-unknown error, you would have been pointed towards the real line at which you wrote invalid code, instead of just assuming that you knew what the problem was and getting it wrong.

Comment: your code changes what the pointer points at `*ptr=11` and where the pointer points `ptr++`. so its not const in either sense

Comment: I do not really get the downvotes. The question is complete.

Answer (score 4):

```
ptr++;
```

What do you think you are doing above? Essentially you are changing **value** of the const pointer (which is different from the value of the object to which the pointer points and which is obtainable via `*ptr`). Hence the error from the compiler.

Also since you used `%p` in `printf` you should cast the value of `ptr` to `void*` instead of what you have (`unsigned int*`).

Comment: The value should be able to change, thats what I am saying, if I try to change the address pointed by it then it should return error

Comment: @sagar You are making the pointer to *point* to a different address using expression I cited. const pointer should not do that.

Answer (score 4):

> but I am just changing the value pointed by it

If you want to change the value of the object pointed to by the pointer that is the object `a[0]` you should write

```
( *ptr )++;
```

or

```
++*ptr;
```

instead of

```
ptr++;
```

In the last expression you are trying to change the constant pointer itself and the compiler evidently issues a diagnostic message.

Take into account that the casting in this statement

```
printf("\n Address pointed by ptr  : [%p]\n",(unsigned int*)ptr);
```

does not make sense. You should write

```
printf("\n Address stored in ptr  : [%p]\n",(void *)ptr);
```

Answer (score 2):

`const char *ptr` - means that objects pointed by pointer are const, but the pointer itself is not

`char * const ptr` - means that the pointer itself is constant but pointed objects are not

`const char * const ptr` - both pointer and pointed ob objects are constant

Answer (score 2):

> and if I try to change the address then it should return error

By its nature the pointer, its value, *is* the address.

So doing

```
p++;
```

tries to change it, which you explicitly forbid by putting the `const` to the right of the `*` in

```
int * const ptr ...
```